# Nativescript core camera integrated in a layer instead of launch camera app to take photos

Tags: javascript, camera, nativescript

I wanted to have a NativeScript core camera integrated inside a layer (StackLayout for example) that can be activated with a custom buttom instead of launch camera app to take a photo and come back to the app qith the result like the example:

```
const camera = require("nativescript-camera");

if (camera.isAvailable()) {
    var options = { width: 300, height: 300, keepAspectRatio: false, saveToGallery: false};
    camera.takePicture(options)   
        .then(function (imageAsset) {
            mv.imageTaken = imageAsset;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
        });
}
```

I found a [plugin](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-camera-preview) about camera preview but it has the text:

> (that might not work)

In this case it will no necesary to have a preview, because I use the imageAsset for getting the tet and fill a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [nativescript-camera-plus](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus) plugin which allows you to embed camera within your layouts.

```
tns plugin add @nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus
```

Comment: That works perfect. Lots of thanks I didn't know that plugin